# How stock a numeric value (diff of 2 date)

Tags: expression, etl, datediff, opentext

I've to calculate the différence between two Dates : TODAY() and DATE_DEB_VAC.
With Oracle, it's kinda easy : `TODAY()-DATE_DEB_VAC` -> give the number of day between those 2 date.

But I've to do it with in an ETL (GENIO). I've a column to stock it like that :
`NUMBER_DAY_DIFF (NUMBER 10) = TODAY()-DATE_DEB_VAC`. But it's impossible to stock it cause it's 2 date.

How can i do this ? :(

Comment: What programming language or technology are you using?  You mentioned Oracle, so you are referring to a database/SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the val function of GENIO ETL

```
VAL(TODAY()-DATE_DEB_VAC)
```

this is equivalent to to_numbre in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

NUMBER_DAY_DIFF (NUMBER 10) = DATEDIFF (TODAY; DATE_DEB_VAC)

Should give you what you need.